# How do i check if the p elements in my div are a valid mathematical expression

Tags: javascript, html, mathematical-expressions

I wanted to check if the `<p>` elements inside my `<div>` with id screen are a valid mathematical expression,doing the validation inside my `operationLogic()` then return the result of whatever was the mathematical expression on my `<div>` with id screen again, but I'm having a hard time into finding out how to do that

```js
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');

function getButtonValue() {
  var element = event.target.innerHTML
  var insert = document.createElement("p");
  if (element == '=') {
    insert.innerHTML = `${operationLogic()}`;
  } else {
    insert.innerHTML = `${element}`;
  }
  screen.appendChild(insert);
};

function operationLogic() {
  let p = screen.querySelectorAll('p');
  let number = ''
  p.forEach(element => {
    let number = +element.innerHTML;
    return Number(number)
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div id=screen></div>
  <div id="operationMain">
    <ul>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">{</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">}</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">(</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">)</li>
      <li class="blue" onclick="getButtonValue()">=</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">+</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">-</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">x</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">÷</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">%</li>
      <li class="operatorColor" onclick="getButtonValue()">.</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">0</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">1</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">2</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">3</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">4</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">5</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">6</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">7</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">8</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">9</li>
      <li onclick="getButtonValue()">00</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Research "how to write a calculator application".

Comment: Please elaborate on what "I'm having a hard time" means

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: i meant im trying to find out how i could make the validation at the second function, but im having a hard time to find out how i could do that

Comment: Here is a better version. You should perhaps save the numbers and operators in an array so you could stack the calculations after an equal https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/92k16c4t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier if you delegate.

It is quite complex to validate and you would need a parser for that

Here is a possible way - extended version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/92k16c4t/)

I had to change x and ÷ to * and /. You can keep them but then we need data-attributes on the LIs instead of textcontent

```js
const screen = document.getElementById('screen');
const ul = document.getElementById('operationMain');

const operationLogic = () => {
  const statement = Array.from(screen.querySelectorAll('p'))
    .map(element => element.textContent.trim())
    .join(' ');
  console.log(statement);
  return statement
};

ul.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const tgt = event.target.closest('li');
  if (!tgt) return;
  let element = tgt.textContent.trim();

  if (element === '=') {
    const expression = operationLogic();
    try {
      const result = math.evaluate(expression);
      console.log('Result:', result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Invalid Expression:', error.message);
    }
  }

  const insert = document.createElement('p');
  insert.textContent = (element === '=') ? `${operationLogic()}` : `${element}`;
  screen.appendChild(insert);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>

<div id="calculator">
  <div id=screen></div>
  <div>
    <ul id="operationMain">
      <li class="operatorColor">{</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">}</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">(</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">)</li>
      <li class="blue">=</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">+</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">-</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">*</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">/</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">%</li>
      <li class="operatorColor">.</li>
      <li>0</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>00</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! this helped me to clarify my struggles